# how to find element selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How do I find

```
 element = driver.find_element_by_id("id","class","class")
```

Im trying to click an ad
doing direct with xpath will not work:

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/img

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 14, in <module>
element = driver.find_element_by_id("/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/img")
```

HTML shown as follows:

```
</head> 
<body scroll="no">
   <div id="widget" class="widget">
   <div class="plug">
   <div class="thumbBorder">
   <div class="thumb">
   <div class="ton" style="display: block;">
      <div class="title_bg"> </div>
      <a class="title q" target="_blank" href="//prwidgets.com/t/ghxa/g0us/7433c239e19107a4301ad9959d2d37440/aHR0cDovL3Ry‌​aXBsZXh2aWQuY29tLw==">Kiss N Tell</a> 
   </div>
   <a class="q" target="_blank" href="//prwidgets.com/t/ghxa/g0us/7433c239e19107a4301ad9959d2d37440/aHR0cDovL3Ry‌​aXBsZXh2aWQuY29tLw=="> <img title="Title" src="//prstatics.com/prplugs/0/747604/160x120.jpg"
```

Comment: add the sample html to make it clear what you want to click on

Comment: @Slslam 
</head>
<body scroll="no">
<div id="widget" class="widget">
<div class="plug">
<div class="thumbBorder">
<div class="thumb">
<div class="ton" style="display: block;">
<div class="title_bg"> </div>
<a class="title q" target="_blank" href="//prwidgets.com/t/ghxa/g0us/7433c239e19107a4301ad9959d2d37440/aHR0cDovL3RyaXBsZXh2aWQuY29tLw==">Kiss N Tell</a>
</div>
<a class="q" target="_blank" href="//prwidgets.com/t/ghxa/g0us/7433c239e19107a4301ad9959d2d37440/aHR0cDovL3RyaXBsZXh2aWQuY29tLw==">
<img title="Title" src="//prstatics.com/prplugs/0/747604/160x120.jpg"

Comment: im trying to click on the <img title to go to link or open

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_id` in Selenium python binding accepts one parameter which is the value of the id attribute. Such as 
`login_form = driver.find_element_by_id('loginForm')`
Please refer to the doc [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id)
Addition to that you can use

`driver.find_element(By.ID, 'your ID')`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can try `xpath`- and `axis` i.e. `following-sibling`

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[class='q']/following-sibling::img[1]")
element.click()
```

N.B I have assumed there is no `a` with class name `q` in the whole html doument.

Comment: @Slslam what do i add in the following-sibling

Comment: Are your content is root html or just iframe/separate window?

Comment: i think is iframes/seperate window

Comment: When ad is clicked with mouse it opens in new window

Comment: html>body>div.contrainer>div.row>div.col-md-12>div.panel.panel-default>div.panel-body>div#pr-ghxa.pr-widget>iframe>html>body>div#widget.widget>div.plug>div.thumbBorder>di.thumb>a.q>img

Answer (score 1):

This may not work for you but when there is not an easy ID or NAME to grab, I go into the browser (I will refer to Firefox) right click on the element, select 'Inspect Element', then right click on the highlighted area in the inspection window and select 'Copy Unique Selector'. Then you can paste this into your code and use:

```
selector = 'pasted string here'
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector) 
element.click()
```

EDIT: using the selector provided by @James below:

```
selector = 'div.plug:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)'
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
element.click()
```

This usually works quite well for me.

EDIT: Add a real example. Try this and see if it works.

```
# open google search page and click the "About" link

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('www.google.com/ncr')
# got the selector below using Firefox 'Inspect Element -> Copy Unique Selector'
about_selector = 'a._Gs:nth-child(3)' 
about = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(about_selector)
about.click()
```

Comment: div.plug:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)

Comment: @James can you post what you tried and what didn't work? E.g. did it throw an exception, etc. I use this all the time and it has been a real time saver for me.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 14, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.plug:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)"}
Stacktrace:
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpVghjFf/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)

Comment: import time
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "40.118.131.11")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080)
profile.update_preferences() 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("http://www.triplexvid.com")
time.sleep(3)

selector = "div.plug:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2) > img:nth-child(1)"
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
element.click()

Comment: the item is within an iframe i noticed today

Comment: html>body>div.contrainer>div.row>div.col-md-12>div.panel.panel-default>div.panel-body>div#pr-ghxa.pr-widget>iframe>html>body>div#widget.widget>div.plug>div.thumbBorder>di.thumb>a.q>img